# Html5 Drag and Drop, Mousewhell event is not fired after dragstart

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I have app where I am doing html5 drag and drop for category sorting, so user can take category and move somewhere he wants.

Everything is fine but sometimes list of categories are huge and if user needs to move it down they want to use mouse wheel to scroll, but the problem is that after dragstart this event is not fired.

PS. Yes if cursor is moved to bottom then browser will scroll but in my app user experience matter since some times they are sorting around 50 categories and it takes alot of time

Here is sample code if you start dragging div and scroll wheel on mouse **no event printed** to console, which means that event is not fired.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }, false);

</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="drag1"  draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69"  style="    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;">Dragg me</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 https://jsfiddle.net/uo00zL0L/ open console, then start dragging div, hold mouse and try to use wheel, you will see no events printed out

Comment: No `droppable` element appears at `html` at jsfiddle?

Comment: @guest271314 so what?:) i want to use catch wheel event between dragstart and dragstop

Comment: How are `dragstart` and `wheel` event related?

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve `DataTransfer` object of `dragstart` event at `wheel` event?

Comment: @guest271314 I need to catch wheel event after dragstart.

Comment: @guest271314 just try my example start draging element and while holding it scroll mouse wheel, you will see that no events are fired, if you release dragging then wheel event is fired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132452/discussion-between-guest271314-and-volodymyr-bilyachat).

Comment: Actually, i see this behaviour in all places. There are very very few user interfaces, which allow scrolling while performing drag and drop. It's a shame. Why would you ever ignore scrolling, ESPECIALLY when dragging something???? I don't get it. Please someone explain to me. Which genius even had this brilliant idea att all?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using ng2-dragula since i am using angular which is port of 
https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar problem and unfortunately can't find any solution. Have you figured out the issue after these years? Is using a drag and drop library the only way? Thanks.